# How to pass a variable in R to a system command?

Tags: r

I have a file that I read like this:

```
input.bed <- as.data.frame(read.table("lamina_filtered.bed", header = FALSE, sep = "\t", 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, quote = ""));
```

I'm trying to invoke a system command . I referred to a previous question where the answer suggested using either `sprintf` or `paste`, but both give me same error:

```
system(sprintf("/usr/local/bin/KentUtils/bedToPsl %s hg38.chom.sizes inp_hg38.psl", input.bed));

system(paste("/usr/local/bin/KentUtils/bedToPsl  hg38.chom.sizes " , input.bed," inp_hg38.psl"));
```

I get this error:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `/usr/local/bin/KentUtils/bedToPsl c("chr1", "chr1",         "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", "chr1", '
```

This is a sample of the input.bed it's a simple bed fileR:

```
   V1       V2       V3
1 chr1 11323785 11617177
2 chr1 12645605 13926923
3 chr1 14750216 15119039
4 chr1 18102157 19080189
5 chr1 29491029 30934636
6 chr1 33716472 35395979
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely at you error.  The command you're trying to execute is something like:

```
/usr/local/.../bedToPsl c("chr1","chr1","chr1") ...
```

You used `paste` to stick a `data.frame` into a system command.  Your OS can't understand R data structures.  Given that your question doesn't include details about what that system call is supposed to receive it's impossible to tell you how to fix this.  But here are some possibilities

- **Scalar Value** - you probably need to do something like `input.bed$V1[1]` to only pass in one string.  Make sure it's quoted (or not) as appropriate
- **File** - often system commands are intended to receive a file path. In this case, you can skip loading in your data at all and just pass the file name.

Comment: is it possible to pass one row? Like `input.bed[1,] ` ? I tried passing the file path and it worked .But  I might need to pass the file row by row to the program, not as an entire set of rows... When I tried `input.bed[1,] ` it didn't work

Comment: The `bedToPsl` utility you are calling expects a `.bed` _file_ as a parameter, not the read-in data frame version. The call shld be `bedToPsl hg38.chom.sizes lamina_filtered.bed inp_hg38.psl` (or something like that). Was your intent to modify the `.bed` file before processing with the `bedToPsl` utility?

Comment: indeed it does.  However I realised that my algorithm would require me to pass one row at a time of my .bed file to `BedtoPsl`. Does this mean I'll have to create many .bed files one row each? Isn't there one way around this?My intent was to do a loop and pass each row of input.bed that I read as a data frame...

Comment: @shadow.T - I don't know the utility you're using, but I would expect that you would write a loop where R would create a .bed file for each row and then call the utility passing in the file name.  You could use the /tmp directory to make sure you don't produce a lot of garbage files that need cleanup.